# Latin Capital Letter 'E' with Circumflex (Ê)

Tags: c, hex

In a C program in Windows 10, I should print the word TYCHÊ on the screen, but I cannot print the letter Ê (Hex code: \xCA):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *Word;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
   Word = "TYCH\xCA";
   printf("%s", Word);
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: `Hex code: \xCA` in which character set (code page)?

Comment: That'd be CP 437, your Windows default, folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows is a pain when it comes to printing Unicode text, but the following should work with all modern compilers (MSVC 19 or later, g++ 9 or greater) on all modern Windows systems (Windows 10 or greater), in both Windows Console and Windows Terminal:

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <windows.h>
   
   int main()
   {
     SetConsoleOutputCP( CP_UTF8 );
     std::cout << "TYCHÊ" << "\n";
   }
```

Make sure your compiler takes UTF-8 as the input character set. For MSVC 19 you need a flag. I think it is the default for later versions, but I am unsure on that point:

```
cl /EHsc /W4 /Ox /std:c++17 /utf-8 example.cpp
g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -O3 -std=c++17 example.cpp
```

EDIT: Dangit, I misread the language tag again. :-(
Here’s some C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
  SetConsoleOutputCP( CP_UTF8 );
  printf( "%s\n", "TYCHÊ" );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dúthomhas. How can I implement this code in the C language?

Comment: @user3472381 Use printf() instead of cout, but otherwise the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this line

```
printf("%s%c", Word, 0x2580 + 82);
```

this can print your Ê.
I used CLion for resolve it, on another IDE it may not give the same result.

Comment: Why should this work? Where do the numbers come from?

Comment: Because with a little imagination you will discover that you will be able to add characters to their hexadecimal value, windows has some problems in this regard, this solution can be effective

Comment: `0x2580 + 82` will be converted by `printf` to `unsigned char`, resulting in `0xD2`. Then you print that after OP's string, whatever the corresponding character is in the output encoding, e.g. `╥` in code page 437. How is that helpful?

Comment: @user3482381 It doesn't, or if it does, it's only by accident. Try other answers.

Comment: Can you please explain _why_ it is supposed to work? Is `0xD2` the value of `Ê` in the relevant encoding? Which encoding is that and what is the purpose of adding to a large number if it is cast back to a char anyway?

Answer (score -1):

In the Windows Command Line you should choose the Code Page 65001:

```
CHCP 65001
```

If you want to silently do that directly from the source code:

```
system("CHCP 65001 > NUL");
```

In the C source code you should use the `<locale.h>` standard header.

```
#include <locale.h>
```

At the beginning of your program execution you can write:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

The empty string `""` initializes to the default encoding of the underlying system (that you previously choose to be Unicode).

However, this answer of mine is just a patch, not a solution.
It will help you to print the french characters, at most.

Handling encoding in Windows command line is not straight.
See, for example: [Command Line and UTF-8 issues](https://entropymine.wordpress.com/2018/11/28/win32-i-o-character-encoding-part-2-chcp-65001/)

Comment: No, please don’t instruct users to do Windows-specific tasks using `system()` calls to cmd.exe.